# Using Math.sqrt() instead of d3.scaleSqrt() for sizing circles on map?

Tags: d3.js

I am building a map where circles appended to cities on a US map are sized based upon a value in the CSV (guns column or `d.guns` in the JavaScript).

I was able to get the circles to resize using `Math.sqrt()` while appending the circles, but I do not think this is the right way to do it (or is it fine?):

```
.attr('r', function(d) {
  return Math.sqrt(d.guns * 0.0010);
})
```

[image: Here's how the map looks right now.]

I attempted to use the `d3.scaleSqrt()` and `d3.extent` to resize the circles based upon the values, but I was thrown these errors in the console:

[image: Console errors]

Here is the code when I attempted using `d3.scaleSqrt`:

```
<head>
  <script>
    function draw(geo_data) {
      'use strict';

      var margin = 75,
        width = 1920 - margin,
        height = 1080 - margin;

      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin)
        .attr('height', height + margin)
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'map');

      var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa();

      var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

      var map = svg.selectAll('path')
        .data(geo_data.features)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', path)
        .style('fill', 'rgba(253, 227, 167, 0.8)')
        .style('stroke', 'black')
        .style('stroke-width', 0.4);

      d3.csv('top100cities.csv', function(error, data) {
    // Converts strings to integers.

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      return d.guns = +d.guns;
    })
        var guns_extent = d3.extent(function(d) {
          return d.guns;
        });

        var radius = d3.scaleSqrt()
          .domain(guns_extent)
          .range([0, 12]);

        svg.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'bubble')
          .selectAll('circle')
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('circle')
          .attr('cx', function(d) {
            return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
          })
          .attr('cy', function(d) {
            return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
          })
          .attr('r', function(d) {
            return radius(d.guns);
          })
          .style('fill', 'rgba(103, 65, 114, 0.5)');

      });

    };
</script>

<body>
<script>
d3.json('us_states.json', draw);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error, I think, was in the retrieval of the max number of guns.

Here is the diff:

```
let guns = data.map( function(d) { return d.guns });
console.log(Math.max(...guns));

var radius = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([0, Math.max(...guns)]).range([0, 25]);
```

Here is the modified demo:

```html
<head>
  <script>
    function draw(geo_data) {
      'use strict';

      var margin = 75,
        width = 1920 - margin,
        height = 1080 - margin;

      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin)
        .attr('height', height + margin)
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'map');

      var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa();

      var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

      var map = svg.selectAll('path')
        .data(geo_data.features)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', path)
        .style('fill', 'rgba(253, 227, 167, 0.8)')
        .style('stroke', 'black')
        .style('stroke-width', 0.4);

  d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dieterholger/US-Gun-Manufacturing-Interactive/master/top100cities.csv', function(error, data) {

    let guns = data.map( function(d) { return d.guns });
    console.log(Math.max(...guns));

    var radius = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([0, Math.max(...guns)]).range([0, 25]);

    svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'bubble')
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
      })
      .attr('r', function(d) {
        return radius(d.guns);
      })
      .style('fill', 'rgba(103, 65, 114, 0.5)');

      });

    };
</script>

<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dieterholger/US-Gun-Manufacturing-Interactive/master/us_states.json', draw);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You're right! Though I don't think the sizing looks any better, really. I'll play with the range. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Although Xavier Guihot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49205812/4235784) is technically correct and proposes a working solution it slightly deviates from the D3 track. The error in your code was caused by not providing all parameters to [`d3.extent()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#extent); you simply forgot to pass in the array, namely `data`, from which to determine the extent (emphasis mine):

> [#](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#extent) d3.extent(*array*[, *accessor*]) [<>](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/src/extent.js)
>
> Returns the [minimum](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#min) and [maximum](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#max) value in the given ***array*** using natural order. Providing both, the array as well as the accessor, your code would look like this:

```
var guns_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {   // Pass in data as first parameter
  return d.guns;
});
```

Below is the working demo:

```js
function draw(geo_data) {
  'use strict';

  var margin = 75,
    width = 1920 - margin,
    height = 1080 - margin;

  var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin)
    .attr('height', height + margin)
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'map');

  var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa();

  var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

  var map = svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(geo_data.features)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', path)
    .style('fill', 'rgba(253, 227, 167, 0.8)')
    .style('stroke', 'black')
    .style('stroke-width', 0.4);

  d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dieterholger/US-Gun-Manufacturing-Interactive/master/top100cities.csv", function(error, data) {
    // Converts strings to integers.

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      return d.guns = +d.guns;
    })
    var guns_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {   // Pass in data
      return d.guns;
    });

    var radius = d3.scaleSqrt()
      .domain(guns_extent)
      .range([0, 12]);

    svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'bubble')
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
      })
      .attr('r', function(d) {
        return radius(d.guns);
      })
      .style('fill', 'rgba(103, 65, 114, 0.5)');

  });

};

d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dieterholger/US-Gun-Manufacturing-Interactive/master/us_states.json', draw);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Comment: From a dataviz perspective it's worth mentioning that OP should not use `extent`: the lowest radius of the circle (zero) should correspond to `0` in the data. Therefore, the best choice for the domain is `[0, max]`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Sure, you are right. That's what I used in the first version of my answer: `[0, guns_extent[1]]` to have a peek at the outcome of that domain, but forgot to edit it out again. I decided to keep this as close to the question as possible without questioning the overall approach, though, to show how small the error was.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the formula for the area of a circle could work.

The formula is `A=πr2`, where `A` equals the area of the circle, `r` equals the radius.

if `A = d.guns`

We know `Area` and `π`

then:

`r = √(d.guns/π)`

`.attr("r", function (d) {return Math.sqrt(d.guns/3.1416);})`

https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Radius-of-a-Circle#/Image:Calculate-the-Radius-of-a-Circle-Step-10-Version-4.jpg